# OBIEE12c answers encounter an Odbc driver error

Tags: oracle, obiee

After migrating OBIEE from 11g to 12c, BI answers encounter the following error.

Odbc driver returned an error (SQLExecDirectW).
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 43113. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. EVALUATE_SUPPORT_LEVEL inside NQSConfig.INI is not set to support EVALUATE. (HY000)

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround can fix the issue.

1. Go to the NQSConfig.INI file location

   File location:$DOMAIN_HOME/config/fmwconfig/biconfig/OBIS/
2. Open the NQSConfig.INI
3. Change the following line

   EVALUATE_SUPPORT_LEVEL = 0;

   to

   EVALUATE_SUPPORT_LEVEL = 2;
4. Restart the OBIEE12c services

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the analysis is using an `evaluate` function which is passing the function down to the database rather than using logical SQL that is interpreted by the BI server.   By default the use of `evaluate` is disabled.

To enable it you set the EVALUATE_SUPPORT_LEVEL in NQSConfig.INI as per the other answer.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/BIMIG/GUID-C2C5B43E-4BB9-4ED7-94DE-D262698DCF98.htm#BIMIG-GUID-C2C5B43E-4BB9-4ED7-94DE-D262698DCF98